# Efficient 2 dimensional array column extraction in Scala

Tags: arrays, scala, collections

Consider a 2 dimensional Array, for instance

```
scala> val a = Array.tabulate(2,3){_+_}
a: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(0, 1, 2), Array(1, 2, 3))
```

How to define a function

```
def getCol(ith: Int, a: Array[Array[Int]]): Array[Int]
```

that delivers

```
val col2 = getCol(2, a)
col2: Array[Int] = Array(1,2)
```

A simple and inefficient approach includes

```
def getCol(ith: Int, a: Array[Int]): Array[Int] = {
  val t = a.transpose
  t(ith)
}
```

Thus to ask also for more efficient ways.

Comment: If you need really efficient code, this is one of the cases where I would probably just go for the while-loop. I doubt a map-operation is very efficient and since the problem is quite simple, this would be my choice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
def getCol(n: Int, a: Array[Array[Int]]) = a.map{_(n - 1)}
```

Note that you have to use `n - 1` for Nth element.

Comment: Can you explain what you did there? :)

Comment: @Ahmedov: `a.map{_(n - 1)}` is just a shorter version of `a.map{innerArray => innerArray(n - 1)}` which is a shorter version of `a.map{innerArray => innerArray.apply(n - 1)}`. "For each inner array of `a` get an element at index `n-1`".

Comment: I have a 2D array with some null values. 2dArray.map(_(n-1)) returns ArrayIndexOutOfBound exception for the columns that contain null values. Any workaround?

Comment: @Ahmedov: could you provide an example?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/sG3BYXAw . This is my local dataset. I want read in the sales column into an Array of Strings. When I say 'val c = localTable.map(_(2))' I get the above mentioned error. I think the problem originates due to the existence of some null values in the "Sales" column, because when I read in the second column I do not get any errors.

Comment: @Ahmedov: according to error you have internal array with less than n elements.

Comment: I don't think it is the case. For example, when I type "println(localTable(0)(2)) 
    println(localTable(4)(2))" I do not get any errors. But, when I say println(localTable(3)(2)) to print a cell with a null value I get java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:

Comment: @Ahmedov [ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) Thrown to indicate that an array has been accessed with an illegal index. The index is either negative or greater than or equal to the size of the array.